# How can I compare and check date of program and the system date in MVS 2012 Coded UI test?

Tags: date, datetime, visual-studio-2012, automation, coded-ui-tests

I am trying to compare and check the date if it is today's date or not in a spesific program. I tried to use assertion method but when I use it the time will remain same if you try it next day. The main problem that I need to know when open a page from program It should be today's date and should be passed. if you know already anything about it please let me know also :)

Thanks yo!

Answer (score 0):

Use `System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")` as one argument of the assertion. You may need to use a different format rather in the `...ToString()` method. The exact format depends on how the date is shown on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

This could be done using "StringAssert" to verify that your programs date string contains today's date string, while ignoring the time:

```
var programDateString = "7/25/2016 12:00:00"; //this is an example of your date retrieved from the application with time included
var todaysDate = System.DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString(); //short date string

StringAssert.Contains(programDateString, todaysDate);
```